# Mono C# and Objective-C NSMutableDictionary

Tags: c#, objective-c, interop, mono

I have written a method in Objective-C (XCode, dylib project) and most methods I've written return an int which is easy to then call from C# (Mono) via DLLImport, however I now need a method that can return a KeyValuePair List (a list of two strings at a time)... I have used an NSMutableDictionary on the XCode end, but how / what does that map to on the C# end?

Or alternatively should I be using something else to return the KeyValuePairs?

Answer (score 0):

Return an array of structures, each structure containing two strings.

Operating on more complex objects through P/Invoke won't be nice or easy (you'd have to marshal them as `IntPtr` and unwrap the memory contents manually).

Comment: Thanks, anyway you could help further as I'm still not sure how to do this, I've added a struct to my header file but now it won't seem to allow me to define the method - (<structname>[])GetStrings... where <structname> is my structs name